# Mongodb Joining multi document with $lookup aggregation operator and search in the joined document using $or at once

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a Purchase order document and this purchase order document has Ids of the supplier and outlet which both of them are separated document (*not embedded).

What I want when user query like this from client-side "give me the purchase order documents which (purchase-order reference-number or supplier name or outlet name) is like "Otilia"

The aggregation query I made so far is this:

```
[
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"outlets",
         "localField":"outlet",
         "foreignField":"_id",
         "as":"outlets"
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"suppliers",
         "localField":"supplier",
         "foreignField":"_id",
         "as":"suppliers"
      }
   },
   {
      "$match":{
         "$and":[
            {
               "$or":[
                  {
                     "outlets.name":{
                        "$regex":".*Otilia.*",
                        "$options":"i"
                     },
                     "referenceNumber":{
                        "$regex":".*Otilia.*",
                        "$options":"i"
                     },
                     "suppliers.name":{
                        "$regex":".*Otilia.*",
                        "$options":"i"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "$sort":{
         "outlets.name":1,
         "_id":1
      }
   }
]
```

What is working:
if I remove the tow other objects from $or array which looks like this

```
[
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"outlets",
         "localField":"outlet",
         "foreignField":"_id",
         "as":"outlets"
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"suppliers",
         "localField":"supplier",
         "foreignField":"_id",
         "as":"suppliers"
      }
   },
   {
      "$match":{
         "$and":[
            {
               "$or":[
                  {
                     "suppliers.name":{
                        "$regex":".*Otilia.*",
                        "$options":"i"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "$sort":{
         "outlets.name":1,
         "_id":1
      }
   }
]
```

Note: I used $and because it could be more filters from client-side like purchase order status and more.

Purchase Order document Sample

[image]

Supplier document Sample:

[image]

outlet document Sample:

[image]

The result I want t to achieve is the matched purchase orders documents by the query.

Comment: Can you provide sample documents from the collections you are trying to join? Can you also provide the results you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: @LaurenSchaefer updated the questin please check.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by wrapping every $or expression with {}.

I just forgot to wrap every $or expression in brackets.

the correct format of the query is this:

```
[
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"outlets",
         "localField":"outlet",
         "foreignField":"_id",
         "as":"outlets"
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"suppliers",
         "localField":"supplier",
         "foreignField":"_id",
         "as":"suppliers"
      }
   },
   {
      "$match":{
         "$and":[
            {
               "$or":[
                  {
                     "orderNumber":{
                        "$regex":".*Celia Pouros.*",
                        "$options":"i"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "supplierInvoice":{
                        "$regex":".*Celia Pouros.*",
                        "$options":"i"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "suppliers.name":{
                        "$regex":".*Celia Pouros.*",
                        "$options":"i"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "$sort":{
         "outlets.name":1,
         "_id":1
      }
   }
]
```